# Getting "Permission to start activity denied" error in logs on running appium test on real device

Tags: appium

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Permission to start activity denied.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 5.41 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
System info: host: 'rude', ip: '192.168.1.8', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

Comment: Format your question properly

Answer (score 1):

Stop the appium server and restart again. 

 This problem will occur when the launcher activity which you set in appium is not the default launch activity. So I suggest you to change the Launcher activity from the dropdown to other activity which is default activity. Try this.
check with developer for default launcher activity

Answer (score 1):

I set ("autoGrantPermissions","true"). Removed appActivity capability and set appWaitActivity and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**A new session could not be created. (Original error: Permission to start activity denied.)**

above error comes when your appium is not started or sometimes Appium stops working with no reason with **error code 500**. So restart appium and run your test.

Answer (score 0):

Some time already developed Application has maintain security.
for opening Application from splash screen to next Activity refer below code,

```
File appDir = new File ("src");

DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);

cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Device");

cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "25");

cap.setCapability("appPackage","com.demo" );

cap.setCapability("appActivity","com.demo.ui.splash.SplashActivity");

cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");

AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<> (new URL("http://117.0.0.1:1723/wd/hub"),cap);
```

Make sure to set  `cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");`
for launching  next activity after Splash activity.